# Why is the generic type parameter T "unknown" in the return type? How can I type this function so that the return type is correctly inferred?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The typescript handbook (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) says this about Generic Constraints:

> You can declare a type parameter that is constrained by another type
> parameter.

In this contrived example, how can I get "T" in in the return type of wrap() to be correctly inferred?

```
function wrap<T, F extends (() => T)>(cb: F): [T, F] {
  return [cb(), cb]
}

function load(): string {
  return ''
}

const [
  value, // unknown, should be string. Can I get typescript to infer this?
  wrapped, // () => string
] = wrap(load)
```

Comment: Is the generic `T` actually necessary? You could use `ReturnType<F>` [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAYogUwA8oCwATAZ0QAoaBKRAXgD5F0wBPelmiAIwBciXPWEBtAEoEoIVGAAqnTATwsANCIC6iAN4BYAFCJEqGXKTiBDTQK1GAvkaOhIsBIgA2cdOQbDKKFQYMABzPSMTM1l5RAByOMdnQwgEQMRxSMQAN3RPEAJNAHoixEDgsKy0LBVyYtKGZjZykNCjHSYUDEwab196IA)

Comment: I think the simplest way of expressing this is `function wrap<T>(cb: () => T): [T, () => T] { return [cb(), cb] }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typescript has problems inferring `T` from a construct like this `func<T, F extends (() => T)>`. In that case, it is usually better to rely on [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html). For your example, we can use the utility type [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype), which uses `infer` internally and does exactly what we need:

```
function wrap<F extends (() => any)>(cb: F): [ReturnType<F>, F] {
  return [cb(), cb]
}

function load(): string {
  return ''
}

const [
  value, // string
  wrapped, // () => string
] = wrap(load)
```